# keep selection after bevel

Tags: edit-mode, bevel, select

I'm trying to simply bevel a subdivided cube and each time I click out or click enter to apply bevel the whole mesh gets selected. I'm trying to keep selection after bevel and it's so frustrating does anyone have any idea why this keeps happening?